# Execution Date from airflow to be passed in SQL parameter with Snowflake Operator

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a simple test script that will write the execution date of the airflow session so that when I back-date it and increment it daily it should give me a recurring day record per row.

```
test_date = SnowflakeOperator(
    Task_Id = 'test_execution_date',
    sql = 'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Execution_Date) VALUES ({{ execution_date }})',
....)
```

I have also tried

```
test_date = SnowflakeOperator(
    Task_Id = 'test_execution_date',
    sql = 'INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Execution_Date) VALUES ({{ params.execution_date }})',
    params = {'exectuion_date': '{{ execution_date }}',
....)
```

Each attempt is trying to write the value 'execution_date' in as the value instead of writing the actual date?

Any suggestions on how I best capture and insert the execution date into SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

No need for params in this case. Just use the macro directly (like you did in the first attempt).
Since you didn't post traceback it's hard to understand why it doesn't work for you but this is probably due to types. `{{ execution_date }}` gives you the plain representation of timestamp but you need to cast it to the proper type Snowflake expect for the INSERT statement or at least use it as string "{{ execution_date }}"  to avoid syntax errors.

Probably something like:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Execution_Date) VALUES ("{{ execution_date }}")"""
```

or

```
sql = """INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Execution_Date) VALUES (TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP("{{ execution_date }}"))"""
```